# Loading js file for all browsers except IE

Tags: 7

I have a requirement to add a js file only for IE (6, 7, 8) browsers. The following script works fine and sometime it doesn't. I cleared the cache several times but has no difference.I don't know where I am going wrong . Is there anything to do with `drupal_add_js` for IE?

```
function mymodule_init() {
  if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE')) {
    $theme_path = drupal_get_path('theme', 'mythemename');
    $js_path = $theme_path . '/script/modernizr.js';
    drupal_add_js($js_path, 'external');
  }
}

// The code modified to true for all browsers it works for all browsers but not in IE 
function mymodule_init() {
  if(1)) {
    $theme_path = drupal_get_path('theme', 'mythemename');
    $js_path = $theme_path . '/script/modernizr.js';
    drupal_add_js($js_path, 'external'); // loading in all browsers except IE
  }
}
```

Comment: The "external" option is not applicable here

Comment: Get rid of your if statement as well, it's not required.

Comment: What I meant to say if you should get rid of the if statement and do browser detection in your javascript.

Comment: Thanks Scott Joudry, removing the external has done the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, you're using [`hook_init`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_init/7) which is not run on cached pages.

Because your cache isn't varying by user agent, you're not getting a consistent response.

An easy solution would be to use something like a conditional IE tag in your theme `html.tpl.php` and add the JS in there:

e.g:

```
<!--[if !IE]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/themes/mytheme/script/modernizr.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

As you may be suspected, the original condition is wrong.  Here's a related post on how someone was able to find a better condition for checking the user agent for IE:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302302/php-if-internet-explorer-6-7-8-or-9

summary: use this instead:

```
if(preg_match('/(?i)msie [1-8]/',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Conditional styles](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_styles) module

> Without this module, the only way to have IE conditional stylesheets
>   was to add [37 lines of code](https://www.drupal.org/node/1031344) (more if you want to add more than one
>   stylesheet) in four horribly-difficult-to-remember function calls to
>   your theme's template.php. Blech. Who wants that?
>
> This module allows Drupal 7 themes to easily add conditional
>   stylesheets to the theme's .info file.